# Magento 2 : Can we pass multiple variables in layout handle?

Tags: magento2, layout, variables

Can we pass multiple variables in layout handle.

like below code :

```
 {{layout handle="email_product_list" order=$order product=$product area="frontend"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass multiple variables in layout handle.

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

For reference :
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Sales/email/invoice_new_guest.html

Comment: when i am doing this it gives error as undefined variable product in phtml file ? what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Thank you @Krishna this reference has helped me to understand the logic